# ¿Cuál es el fichero training_data.json que aparece en este código en Python sobre añadir imágenes en VisualRecognition de ibm watson?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

En la línea 10 aparece en el fichero en Python para añadir una imagen a un modelo de ibm watson de visual recognition:  'training_data.json', pero no sé cómo implementarlo. Mil gracias de antemano.

````
import json
from ibm_watson import VisualRecognitionV4
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('my authenticator')
visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV4(
    version='2019-02-11',
    authenticator=authenticator)

visual_recognition.set_service_url('https://api.eu-de.visual-recognition.watson.cloud.ibm.com')

with open('training_data.json') as trainingData:
    result = visual_recognition.add_images(
        collection_id='52e059a4-7310-4a6e-8101-de80b4826814',
        images_file=['./raccoon1.zip'],training_data=trainingData.read()).get_result()        
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2)) ```
````

Comment: ¿Cuál es la fuente de la que has obtenido el código? Ese archivo parece ser un set inicial de configuraciones o datos que utiliza el programa, en la fuente debe de mencinar cómo generar ese archivo o de dónde obtenerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya recibí respuesta por email de IBM:

You wrote,
I would like to know where is the training_data.json file that appears in this line:
with open('training_data.json')

about the page https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/visual-recognition-v4?code=python#addimages

The name of the file "training_data.json" is an example. You provide a set of images with labeled training data to train the service.

For some more information, take a look at the documentation at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-object-detection-overview

Please note that IBM Watson Visual Recognition is discontinued. Existing instances are supported until 1 December 2021, but as of 7 January 2021, you can't create instances. Any instance that exists on 1 December 2021 will be deleted.

Comment: Te recomiendo mucho leer [answer], las respuestas esperadas en la plataforma deben ser en español, anexo ayudaría indiques en la misma como es que soluciona el problema expuesto